# Data consistency / fault tolerance with Corda

Tags: corda

When a node lost its date and restored from the backup, how Corda ensure the transaction data still being consistent with its counterparts?

Let’s say, “Bank A paid bank B $10”. Bank A and B each has this transaction data in their vault. Now Bank A lost the data and recovered. It must be “Bank A paid bank B $10”, but what if Bank B tweaked it a bit like “Bank A paid bank B $1”. ? How to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction stating that “Bank A paid Bank B $10” will be signed by Bank A using a public key belonging to Bank A.

If Bank B tries to modify the contents of this transaction (for example to “Bank A paid bank B $1”), this would modify the hash of transaction, which would invalidate Bank A's signature. Bank A would therefore instantly be aware upon checking the transaction's signatures that something had been modified.